# logstash multine filter for lines without date

Tags: logstash

I'm looking for a a logstash multiline filter. Here are my requirements:

- Any line that begins with whitespace or empty line belongs to the previous line
- And any line that does not start with a date timestamp belongs to the previous line

The first part is below for spaces and empty lines but how do I add the second part.

> ```
> multiline {        
>     pattern => "^\s|^$"
>     what => "previous"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can ignore the first condition since it describes a subset of the lines in the second condition, i.e. any line for which the first condition is true also matches the second condition. You should therefore be able to get away with the following (adjust depending on the timestamp format):

```
multiline {
  pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
  negate => true
  what => "previous"
}
```